# eine Frage nach / zu / über etwas

Tags: usage, preposition

I can't grasp the usage of prepositions with the word ***Frage***. Do all the prepositions sound correct in the following sentence? Is there any difference in meaning?

> Sie stellte keine *Fragen* ***nach*** seinem Leben.
>   Sie stellte keine *Fragen* ***zu*** seinem Leben.
>   Sie stellte keine *Fragen* ***über*** sein Leben.

How about these phrases?

> die Frage ***nach dem*** / ***zum*** / ***über den*** Sinn des Lebens
>   eine Frage ***nach dem*** / ***zum*** / ***über den*** Inhalt des Buches

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*nach* / *zu* / *über* – you can't use all three in the same example.

***nach*** is used in contexts where you plan to find something, to follow something up or to pursue (etwas nachgehen):

> Sie fragte nach dem Weg
>
> Wir fragen nach dem Sinn unseres Lebens
>
> Er fragte nach dem Kellner, aber niemand kam.

You wouldn't ask "nach seinem Leben" because this would imply you didn't know if he even had one. But you would express this differently, anyway.

***zu*** is used the same way as "to" with the basic meaning of moving towards a certain topic in order to explore it. Keep in mind that we usually don't "fragen (jemanden) zu" but "befragen (jemanden) zu" a topic.

> Es wurden viele Fragen zu diesem Thema gestellt.
>
> Die Polizisten stellten Fragen zum Vorleben des Verdächtigen.
>
> Die Expertin wurde zum Inhalt ihres Buches intensiv befragt. (or just: zu ihrem Buch)

"Die Expertin wurde *nach* ihrem Buch gefragt" would mean, as one possibility, that she hadn't taken the book to the presentation, or that the book still wasn't available although she had talked about it for some time already, and so on.

***über*** (about) is rarely used when it comes to questions, at most with the verbs "ausfragen" or "befragen":

> Er wurde von der Reporterin über seinen Nachbarn ausgefragt.
>
> Die Polizei befragte den Lenker über den Hergang des Unfalls.

*Über* is rather used to indicate what is being talked about or told. The dinstiction between *über* and *von* is quite delicate:

> Sie sprach oft über die Scheidung ihrer Eltern.

But: Sie sprach oft *von* ihrer Mutter.

> Erzähl mir etwas über dein Leben.

But: Er erzählte mir *von* seinem Abenteuer / Er erzählte mir oft eine Geschichte über einen Bankraub, den er begangen haben wollte (doubtful) / Er erzählte oft Geschichten aus seinem Leben.

In the light of this (and to my judgement), "sie stellte keine Fragen *zu* seinem Leben" would be the best alternative, although I am sure that native speakers wouldn't feel offended by "Fragen über sein Leben". A third solution would be "sie stellte keine Fragen, die sein Leben betrafen".

Answer (score 9):

I'd roughly map them to the following English phrases:

> the question **asking for**/**regarding**/**about**