# Wegen, bezüglich, über. Is their use interchangeable?

Tags: translation, meaning

Is the use of the words wegen, bezüglich and über always interchangeable when we want to say "about" (concerning)? If not, can in some cases be interchangeable?

For example what is the best way for someone to say:
"I want to talk to you about this problem" ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference between these three is quite subtle.

"Über" is a literal translation for "about" and is used most often.

I would translate "bezüglich" as concerning, so the difference between "about" and "concerning" is about the same as between "über" and "bezüglich"

"Wegen" on the other hand implies a reason, where the other two refer more to a topic. Suitable translations might be "because of", "on account of" or "due to"

There's also the grammatical difference:

'über' requires a following accusative where
'wegen' and 'bezüglich' require a genitiv

Comment: "wegen" and "bezüglich" require a genitive, with some exceptions.

Comment: I'd add, that often these differences are ignored in casual language and the words *are* used interchangeably.

Answer (score 3):

**Wegen** (+ [genitive, sometimes dative](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wegen)) indicates a reason or cause:

> Das Freiluftkonzert wurde *wegen* des schlechten Wetters abgesagt. *Wegen* dir mussten wir zwei Stunden warten!

(The concert was cancelled due to bad weather. We had to wait two hours because of you!)

*Wegen* introduces a construction with a noun within a main clause where *weil* puts the same (or an extended) statement into a separate clause:

> Das Konzert wurde abgesagt, *weil* das Wetter schlecht war. Wir mussten zwei Stunden warten, *weil* du nicht aufgetaucht bist.

**Bezüglich** (+ genitive) usually refers to an item already mentioned and is mainly used in a very formal context:

> *Bezüglich* der Vorstandswahl wurden vom Unternehmen noch keine Entscheidungen bekanntgegeben. *Bezüglich* Ihrer Gehaltserhöhung bitte ich Sie noch um etwas Geduld.

(As to the election of the board, the company hasn't announced a decision yet. Regarding your raise, I would like to ask you for a little patience)

**Über** (+ accusative) is used to indicate directly what is being talked about or told. [about the differences between *über*, *von*, and *zu* [see this answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18612/eine-frage-nach-zu-%C3%BCber-etwas/20901#20901)
]:

> Er wurde von der Reporterin *über* seinen Nachbarn ausgefragt. Die Polizei befragte den Lenker *über* den Hergang des Unfalls. Sie sprach oft *über* die Scheidung ihrer Eltern.

(He was quizzed by the reporter about his neighbour. The police questioned the driver about the accident. She often talked about her parents' divorce.)

Now what would be the preposition of choice for your sentence "I want to talk to you about this problem"?

1. Wegen dieses Problems möchte ich mit dir sprechen. =  Because this problem exists, I would like to talk to you.
2. Bezüglich dieses Problems möchte ich mit dir sprechen = Referring to this problem, I would like to talk to you.
3. Über dieses Problem möchte ich gerne mit dir sprechen = I would like to talk that problem over with you.

Thus, *über* seems to be the best alternative in terms of a preposition, but you could also say:

> Ich möchte mit dir dieses Problem besprechen.

Comment: "wegen dir" is grammatically incorrect. "wegen" always requires genitiv. correct form to express "wegen dir" would be "deinetwegen". Same is valid for "seinetwegen" (3rd person), "meinetwegen" (1st person) etc. dative is always colloquial. Also see Duden: www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wegen#block-duden-tiles-6

Answer (score 1):

*Wegen Deiner Antwort bezüglich der Frage über Hustenbonbons müssen wir reden.*

Hier haben wir die Unterschiede, *wegen* ist der Grund, *bezüglich* ist der Topic und *über* ist die Sache worüber gesprochen wurde.

Hier ist nicht alles austauschbar.

Comment: `bezüglich` ist nicht unbedingt das Thema, über das gesprochen wird, aber es gibt einen *Bezug* zum Thema, es wird vielleicht am Rande gestreift, verallgemeinert, spezifiziert, …

Answer (score 0):

They are interchangeable as prepositions though the meaning will slightly change and you have to adopt the Kasus.